# how to show live chat option in magento when support team is online

Tags: websites

I am developing my website in magento, I want to add live chat option if my support team is online.so how can i do that task.
also suggest which is best extension for live chat in magento

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have not advertising in extension
Visit link:-
1)http://www.livechatinc.com/kb/magento-integration-guide/

How to use Magento Live Chat on Your Online Store
2)https://www.cminds.com/how-to-use-magento-live-chat-on-your-online-store/

Magento Live Chat Plugin Start Now for Free
3)https://mylivechat.com/addons/magento-live-chat.aspx

Comment: how to edit "New products" on home page in rwd template in magento